# Script to modify putty settings

Tags: putty

I'm using putty (terminal emulator, serial console). Every time I use it I need to change the font size and background color in setting. Is there any script that I can run so that all settings will be changed automatically? Is it possible for me to change them through scripts?

Comment: Windows or Linux? On Windows I use a Registry file to set settings. Only have to do it once.

Comment: For windows. How to use the registry file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is on Windows then

- Start it from a shortcut
- While the window is still open.
- Right click on the Caption bar
- Select Properties
- Select Font and Colour tabs to change the respective properties
- And Press **OK**